# How to create a service in linux?

Tags: linux, service, systemctl

I am learning to create a service in linux , I am following this [guide](https://www.ubuntudoc.com/how-to-create-new-service-with-systemd/). I am tasked with creating a script that generates a random number between two given numbers. To generate a random number I am using:

```
shuf -i 30-60 -n 1
```

My program file script.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash

function start()
{
   shuf -i 30-60 -n 1  --pidfile = /tmp/randn.pid
    echo "PID is $(cat /tmp/randn.pid)"
}
function stop()
{
    echo "Randn: Stopping Service (PID = $(cat /tmp/randn.pid))"
    kill $(cat /tmp/randn.pid)
    rm /tmp/randn.pid
}

function status()
{
    ps -ef | grep randn | grep -v grep
    echo "PID indicate indication file $(cat /tmp/randn.pid 2&gt; 
/dev/null)" 
}

touch /var/lock/randn

box "$ 1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    reload)
        stop
        sleep 1
        start
        ;;
    status)
        status
        ;;
    *)
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

My .service file is working fine and its output is showing:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/randn.service; enabled; vendor preset;enabled )
Active: failed (Result:exit--code) ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/service.sh --option=start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Failed to start service.
```

I think there is a problem with the the way I am generating random numbers in the above posted script. Can someone please point out what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure where to start ... you can't willy-nilly decide to hand out PID's, that's the OSes decision, not yours.

Comment: Do you think the pid and lock are adding nothing to functionality of programme ?